# set pdfauthor using complex list-processing macro

Tags: hyperref, pdf, etoolbox, metadata

I have created a macro, `\joinlist`, that adds commas or other delimiters between the elements of an `etoolbox` internal list.  It has special handling for lists of just two elements ("a and b").  It also knows how to put a different delimiter between the last two items of longer lists ("a, b, and c").  Here is the definition, created by me:

```
% typical use: \joinlist{\listmacro}{, }{, and }{ and }

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\@join@ignore}[1]{} % used to ignore current list element when counting
\newcount\@join@listlength % used to count length of list
\newcount\@join@currentnum % used to track current list element number

\newcommand{\joinlist}[4]{%
  %
  % count list elements
  \@join@listlength 0 %
  \forlistloop{\advance\@join@listlength 1\relax\@join@ignore}{#1}%
  %
  % now join list elements, tracking current element number
  \@join@currentnum 0 %
  \forlistloop{%
    \advance\@join@currentnum 1 %
    \ifnumequal{\the\@join@currentnum}{1}%
    {}% first
    {% not first
      \ifnumequal{\the\@join@currentnum}{\the\@join@listlength}%
      {% last
        \ifnumequal{\the\@join@listlength}{2}%
        {#4}% last of exactly two
        {#3}% last of more than two
      }%
      {#2}% neither first nor last
    }%
  }%
  {#1}}
```

Save the above as `join-list.sty`, then consider the following small example showing a problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{join-list}

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\people}[0]{}
    \listadd{\people}{a}
    \joinlist{\people}{, }{, and }{ and }  % a

    \listadd{\people}{b}
    \joinlist{\people}{, }{, and }{ and }  % a and b

    \listadd{\people}{c}
    \joinlist{\people}{, }{, and }{ and }  % a, b, and c

    \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\joinlist{\people}{, }{, and }{ and }}

\end{document}
```

`\joinlist` works fine for creating document body content.  We see "a", then "a and b", then "a, b, and c" as expected.

Unfortunately, using this in `\hypersetup{pdfauthor=...}` does not work as hoped.  Instead, it sets the document's PDF author metadata to "0 1110 1 , and a1 , and b1 , and c".  Clearly something has gone badly wrong with expanding/evaluating the `\joinlist` macro in this context.

What am I doing wrong here?  How can I fix this?  Are there other ways that my `\joinlist` macro could be improved?  Does a similar macro already exist in some widely-available package?  (I searched but found none.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `\joinlist` is not "expandable": it must perform assignments such as `\advance\@join@currentnum 1` that can't be done in the value of `pdfauthor=`.

With `expl3` (the not any more so experimental programming layer for LaTeX3), there is what you need.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\joinlist}{ m m m m }
 {
  \seq_use:cnnn { g_liblit_list_#1_seq } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nnnn { c }
\NewDocumentCommand{\newlist}{ m }
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_liblit_list_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listadd}{ m m }
 {
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_liblit_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newlist{people}
\listadd{people}{a}
\joinlist{people}{ and }{, }{, and } % a

\listadd{people}{b}
\joinlist{people}{ and }{, }{, and }  % a and b

\listadd{people}{c}
\joinlist{people}{ and }{, }{, and }  % a, b, and c

\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\joinlist{people}{ and }{, }{, and }}

\end{document}
```

There are some changes with respect to your setting. Lists have a name, rather than be called by a macro; a new one can be created by `\newlist`. Also the order of the arguments to `\joinlist` is different:

1. the list name;
2. what should go between the elements in case of two elements;
3. what should go between the elements when there are more than two (except the last two);
4. what should go between the *last* two elements when there are more than two.

In case the list is empty nothing will be produced; with only one element, that one will be produced.

This version of `\joinlist` is expandable and there's no problem in giving it as a value to `pdfauthor=`.

You can use the code in the preamble as a drop replacement of yours in the `.sty` file.

[image]

Comment: Since you reference the original problem being the use of assignments (causing the non-expandability), yours does not use any assignments, correct?

Comment: @Werner Courtesy of Bruno Le Floch (and the LaTeX3 team), `\seq_use:Nnnn` works by pure expansion.

Comment: This looks encouraging!  But I am seeing an error: `Control sequence \seq_use:Nnnn undefined.`  Perhaps my version of some supporting code is out-of-date?  I am using `expl3` version 2729, dated 2011/09/05, from TeXLive 2011.

Comment: @BenLiblit Sorry, but this is available only with an up-to-date TeX distribution. And TeX Live 2011 is surely obsolete: in a few weeks the test version of the 2013 release will be available.

Comment: Confirmed as working under TeXLive 2012.  Looks like it's time to ask my system administrators to update our installation!

Comment: Here's a helpful hint to anyone trying this in the future. The undefined `\seq_use:Nnnn` control sequence is still undefined if using an initial installation of TeXLive 2012. However, if your TeXLive 2012 installation is fully up-to-date (`tlmgr update --all`), then egreg's solution does work.